# Drupal 7: Populate node fields with values from $form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields, drupal-nodes

I would like to know if it's possible to populate a node fields with the values from form_state or something like that.

Basically what I do is to show a register form merged with a form from a Content Type. I do that by using field_attach_form(). Now on submit I create a node using:

`$node = new stdClass();
 $node->type = 'company';
 $node->uid = 1;
 node_object_prepare($node);`

and now I would like to get all values from form_state and put them into the node.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hook your form, add new submit handler and place your code there.

Comment: And the values to insert in the node? How do I put them there?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't think you understand my question. I know how to create a node pragmatically; the problem I have is that I need to put the values from the $form and $form_state in the node. Without doing something like: $node->title = $form['bla bla]; I would guess something like creating an object from $form and then do node_save($that_object);

Comment: Also, I've tried something like node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);but with no results. It just gives me a blank page.

Comment: A-ha,...sorry then. I manually read and store values as you explained. Don't know for any other way.